# Get Multiple Inputs from User - Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, texteditingcontroller

I have a form with about 15 textform fields to input data by the user. What is the best solution for this?

I have currently created a list like below:

```
List<TextEditingController> textController = [
    TextEditingController(), //name
    TextEditingController(), //location
    TextEditingController(), //days
    TextEditingController(), //year
    TextEditingController(), //hour
    TextEditingController(), //minutes
    TextEditingController(), //seconds
    TextEditingController(), //lat_dec
    TextEditingController(), //lng_dec
    TextEditingController(), //lat_deg
    TextEditingController(), //lat_min
    TextEditingController(), //lat_sec
    TextEditingController(), //lng_deg
    TextEditingController(), //lng_min
    TextEditingController(), //lat_sec
  ];
```

Can I reuse the the same TextEditingController to avoid so many variables?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can generate list with specified size or create map of textEditingControllers and assign value to textfield based on requirement

Comment: Generating a list is much the same as above. Can you elaborate on the Map? Thanks

Comment: its same. you have to run loop to set map with ids  like map.update(key, value =>TextEditingContoller())

Answer (score 0):

using the same `TextEditingController` for more than `TextField` has unexpected behavior which is:

**The text you are typing in a specific field will be simultaneously written to other fields that are controlled with the same controller.**

so, try to handle it through creating a `map of controllers` or even generate a `list` with specific length of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to create a dynamic list of `TextEditingController()` for every item/title without having to manually create them:

```
List<String> titles = ['name','location'];
List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];

for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      controllers.add(TextEditingController());
}
```

See demo: https://dartpad.dev/?id=5019539e54a2f8434df83e6508d3ceea